# SQL Studio Prepared Statement

Tags: sql-server

I am doing work for a company that stores each of their client's info in a different database. When a table needs modification, I have to go to each database and run the `ALTER TABLE` script. Is there a way I can use a prepared statement to run through all 100+ DBO names?

```
ALTER TABLE ?.dbo.profileTable
ADD COLUMN profileStatus int
```

where ? = `'CompanyA, CompanyB, CompanyC'` or something similar?

Comment: Have a look into `sp_MSforeachtable` procedure.

Comment: @Mihai-DanielVirna do you mean sp_MSforeachdb?

Comment: Be very careful if using sp_msforeachdb. It will sometimes skip databases. Here is an alternative. https://sqlblog.org/2018/10/22/sp-ineachdb-2

Comment: If you don’t mind my asking, why a different database for each client? If the tables are similar enough to warrant a bulk `ALTER`, why can’t they be merged into a single database?

Comment: @Manngo Not my design, not in my power to do such a migration. Helping with a very large legacy system. I have no idea why they set it up this way to begin with. So far I've seen no benefits, just nuisances like the one mentioned in the post.

Answer (score 2):

[Use Sp_MSforeachdb](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/joew/archive/2008/08/27/60700.aspx)

```
EXECUTE master.sys.sp_MSforeachdb 'USE [?]; alter query'
```

`[?]` is used as a placeholder for the heretofore unspecified database name

You can modify the query as per your needs ,to exclude system databases use like below..

```
 EXECUTE master.sys.sp_MSforeachdb 'USE [?]; IF DB_ID(''?'') > 4 begin yourquery end'
```

Comment: Will this not throw an error when it tries to execute against system databases?

Comment: @JoeC:   see updated,you can alter query as per your needs

Answer (score 1):

This will exclude any database that does not have the table you are looking for including system databases.

```
Declare @TableName Varchar(8000) = 'ProfileTable'
Declare @Sql Varchar(8000)

Select @Sql = Stuff(
(Select ';', 'Alter Table ' + Name + SqlText
    From sys.databases
    Cross Apply (Select '.dbo.profileTable ADD profileStatus int' SqlText) CA
    Where Case When State_Desc = 'ONLINE'
            Then Object_Id (QuoteName(Name) + '.[dbo].' + @TableName, 'U')
        End Is Not Null

    FOR XML PATH('')
),1,1,'')

Exec (@Sql)
```

Answer (score 0):

This `?` before is database (`[database].[schema].[table]`). Thus you can use `sp_MSforeachdb` or, as I prefer, use `sys.databases` view to prepare dynamic queries.

Beware, both methods can interfere with system databases.

Take a look at this solution:

```
DECLARE @query nvarchar(MAX)='';

SELECT @query = @query + 'USE '+QUOTENAME(name)+';ALTER TABLE dbo.profileTable ADD profileStatus int;'
FROM sys.databases
WHERE OBJECT_ID(QUOTENAME(name)+'.dbo.profileTable', 'U') IS NOT NULL

EXEC(@query)
```

It adds column `col1 int` to each dbo.profileTable in every database.